# Git Post Catastrophe Team Workflow with Sencha Touch and Cordova

Tags: git, cordova, extjs, merge, workflow

## Quick Version

### The Problem

- Our team struggles with git. Unfortunatly I am the most knowlegable in Git and have been fight a battle to keep us using it.
- We develope iOS apps with Sencha Touch and Cordova.
- There's a lot of generated files.
- Some are generated then we need to modify.
- 3 out of 4 of us need to be able to create builds for the iOS device.
- One of us is a QA person that needs to be able to test changes in branches.
- The QA person is learning to make changes to code and will need to merge as well.

### The Goal

- Make merging cleaner. Less generated content throwing conflicts. Ideally it would be nice if there was a way have a command run after a merge is complete. example: `sencha app refresh && sencha app build` I could make a script to do this but not sure how to make sure it ends up in the other persons `.git/hooks` folder. I think this would cover the majority of issues if generated files are ignored.
- Not sure if this is a wise idea but having a branch meant specifically building for Cordova. I think this would solve the issues with some generated files need to be edited. Once a build is functional we can tag that spot with the version
- I'm trying to figure out a way to implement this as simply as possible. If it's too complicated I fear some will not keep using it.

## Slightly Longer Version

There's a few other concerns I have about merging. I'm no expert in Git. I've attempted to find the safest way to merge two branches and get the desired outcome but just when I feel confident in that it fails me. We do work in the same files at the same time quite a bit. I've tried to encourage shorter branch lives to reduce issues but in reality this is not always practical.

#### Theoretical Git Workflow

With tons of Googling only find examples of simple merge conflicts. Not how to resolve hundreds of them. I am really interested if anyone has had to deal with that and how they manage it.

In an attempt to resolve these problems I've been trying to make a workflow for the team to follow. It's kind of reverse order in the comments below.

```
master                      # maybe master will contain deploy tags from completed builds
└── build                   # once qa is ready changes will be added to cordova build
    └── qa                  # dev work will merge into qa when ready
        └── development     # dev work done off of this branch
            ├── feature-01  # normal work
            └── feature-02  # normal work
```

I'm open to other suggestions if anyone disagrees with this workflow.

#### Good Ignore Stragegy?

Due to a recent issue where IDE settings were somehow included in a merge, this really screwed some things up. 
This wouldn't have been as big of an issue except the person on the recieving end had no idea what was going on and made things worse in the process. It was a bit of a nightmare to fix. So that inspired me to make a standard gitignore file for each of us to use. It was basically mine but I added some instructions to the top.

I do wonder if there is a more efficient way to apply an ignore file to all branches that already exist? This solves the problem in this one case but each existing branch will need to go through this process. Am I wrong?

New `.gitignore` file contents

```
#### ------------------------------------------------------------
#### UPDATING YOUR GITIGNORE
#### ------------------------------------------------------------
#
#   cd path/to/project
#   open -a TextEdit .gitignore
#
#### ------------------------------------------------------------
#### paste the contents of this file into your .gitignore file. 
#### if you do not have one save this file as .gitignore to the
#### root of your project. Now quite your IDE.
#### ------------------------------------------------------------
#
#   git rm -r --cached .
#
#### ------------------------------------------------------------
#### delete any files or folders you do not want
#### ------------------------------------------------------------
#
#   git add .
#   git commit -m 'updated tracking to allow gitignore updates to work'
#
#### ------------------------------------------------------------

# GIT

.git
*.orig

# IDE GENERATED

nbproject/
.idea/
.idea_modules/
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws

# SENCHA

.sencha_backup/
archive/
build/
resources/sass/.sass-cache/
resources/css/app.css
```

### The Project Structure for Reference

#### Sencha Touch Project structure

1st level files/folders only

```
APPNAME
├── .git
├── .gitignore
├── .sencha/                # I am on the fence about whether to ignore or not.
├── app/
├── app.js          
├── app.json                # a lot like a package.json file in node
├── bootstrap.js            # best I know is it contains a classname map to pre built src before compiling
├── bootstrap.json          # contains refs for index.html to external files like css and js
├── build/                  # contains testing, production builds for web, but production build is copied to cordova
├── build.xml
├── cordova/                # has all things related to xcode and native app. there are some
|                           # custom changes in here so we try to avoid rebuilding from zero.
├── index.html      
├── resources/              # images, fonts, sass, css etc
└── touch/                  # sencha framework
```

#### Cordova directory structure

I tried to leave out anything I thought wasn't necessary

The files starting with USERNAME I changed. Does anyone know if these should be ignored? I feel like they should. This ties back to the issue with more than one of us able to create a build with out weird issues.

```
cordova
├── config.xml
├── hooks/
├── platforms
│   └── ios
│       ├── CordovaLib
│       │   ├── Classes
│       │   └── CordovaLib.xcodeproj
│       │       └── xcuserdata
│       │           └── USERNAME.xcuserdatad    # ignore?
│       │               └── xcschemes
│       ├── cordova
│       │   └── lib
│       ├── APPNAME
│       │   ├── Classes
│       │   ├── Images.xcassets
│       │   │   ├── AppIcon.appiconset
│       │   │   └── LaunchImage.launchimage
│       │   ├── Plugins
│       │   └── Resources
│       ├── APPNAME.xcodeproj
│       │   ├── project.xcworkspace
│       │   │   ├── xcshareddata
│       │   │   └── xcuserdata
│       │   │       └── USERNAME.xcuserdatad    # ignore?
│       │   └── xcuserdata
│       │       └── USERNAME.xcuserdatad        # ignore?
│       │           └── xcschemes
│       ├── platform_www
│       └── www
├── plugins/
└── www
    ├── app.js
    ├── index.html
    ├── css
    ├── img
    ├── js
    └── resources
```

I'm sorry this is so long. I hope this makes sense. If anyone made it to the end thanks for reading. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: My advice: back out now and/or find a reputable consultant. Multiple misunderstandings have caused many problems, and your requests include unnecessary details and omit necessary ones -- for instance, omitting every concrete detail about a merge problem except "it fails me" -- and at least some of the solutions you describe look to have compounded the trouble.  Individually the problems I can see at least could be simple, and I might easily enough have missed something -- it's Sunday AM after all -- but they all involve learning. I'd say you put it in production too soon. Much too soon.

Comment: Oh ok I see what you mean. I was able to solve the issues but I'm hoping to avoid them in the future. Where I mention ..it fails me.. I could have said that better. I have been trying to give the team an explanation of "if you do it this way it will be less painful"

Comment: Tho as of writing this this morning I managed to gather my thoughts in a way that simplified the issue. Running thought the issue again from the beginning without a long week of late nights I was able to work thought it. I updated the ignore, recreated the track cache, found what files were missing with the git log and and checked those out to current head to restore them. It was a breeze. Of course I had some new knowledge under my belt and didn't have the panic of the developer in my ear. When I took the time to carefully look at everything it was no sweat :)

Comment: Glad to hear this, cheers for pulling it out, thanks for updating. Good luck to you.

Comment: Thanks! Oh just as a side stack overflow question. Should I update those thoughts into the main post?

Comment: The idea is usually that people can google for a concise question or situation. A good post-mortem after near-disasters is always good to do anyway, I'm just not sure it belongs here.

Comment: If you were able to solve your problem yourself, I think that you should add it as an answer. Your current strategies, work-flow, etc. It might help someone....

Comment: Will do! I actually have been wanting to do that but have been giving it some time to make sure. Thanks! I'll start putting that together. Did you have any questions about it I might be able to help with in the meantime?